# Changing Root URL of Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When i run my project, starting url is **http://localhost:8080/shah/**

I want staring url as **http://localhost:8080/shah/welcome**

Here, a method of a controller has @RequestMapping("/welcome")

Where to change the root url??

I am using annotation based configuration with following classes:

Initializer.java

```
@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {DatabaseConfig.class };
    }

     @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
         return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

WebAppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.ism.shah")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    // Maps resources path to webapp/resources
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
    }

    // Provides internationalization of messages
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new 
                         ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

 }
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.ism.shah")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER   = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL      = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = 
                "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = 
                "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = 
                 "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName
    (env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty
            (PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty
                 (PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty
             (PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, 
         env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, 
         env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    return properties;  
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new 
        HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new 
          LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

      sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan
      (env.getRequiredProperty(
        PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to deploy the application as `ROOT.war`

Comment: Where is your controller class? show it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse or simply STS.
Step1. Remove your project from Server under servers tab. 
Step2. Right click on the project, select Properties, Web Project Settings, update the context root here from 'shah' to 'shah/welcome'. 
Then You can run your project again on the respected server.